# Streaming Web camera to a client

Tags: javascript, php, html, flash, camera

I want to stream web camera output (it could be a virtual camera too) to a client's browser. Assume that the web camera is connected to a server. So i want to send the output to a client browser.

For testing purposes, I have setup an Apache local server and I can access the server from any machine connected to the local network.

So is it possible to send the web camera output to other machines through the web? (I know it is possible. I still couldn't figure out a way to do it.) Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: use webrtc see the demo here http://www.webrtc.org/demo